# Yahoo Pipes: Extracting number from feed item for use in URL builder

Tags: yahoo-pipes, bing-api, wolframalpha

Been looking all over the place for a solution to this issue. I have a Yahoo Pipe (http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=e5420863cfa494ee40e4c9be43f0e812) that I've created to pull back image content from the Bing Search API. The URL builder includes a $skip attribute that takes an integer and uses it to select the starting (index) point for the result set that the query returns.

My initial plan had been to use the math engine in the Wolfram Alpha API to generate a random number (randomInteger[1000]) that I could use to seed the $skip value each time that the pipe is run. I have an earlier version of the pipe where I was able to get the query / result steps working using either "XPath Fetch" and "Fetch Data". However, regardless of how I Fetch the result, the response returns as an attribute / value pair in a list item.Even when I use "Emit items as string" in XPath Fetch, I still get a list with a single item, when what I really want is the integer that I can plug into my $skip attribute.

I've tried everything in Pipes I can think of, and spent a lot of time online looking for an answer. Is there anyway to extract text (in this case, a number) from a single list item and then use the output as input to "wire" a text parameter in another Pipes block? Any suggestions / ideas welcome. In the meantime, I'm generating a sorta-random number by manipulating a timecode hash, but it just feels tacky :-)

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a pipe that takes a text parameter, you can embed that pipe in the **Loop** operator of another pipe. Have you tried something like that?

Answer (score 0):

All the sources are for repeated items.  You can't have a source that just makes a single number.

I'm not really clear what you're trying to do.  You want to put a random number into part of the URL string that gets an RSS feed?